# How to dynamically update a plot in a loop in IPython notebook (within one cell)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Environment: Python 2.7, [Matplotlib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matplotlib) 1.3, IPython notebook 1.1, Linux, and Chrome. The code is in one single input cell, using `--pylab=inline`.

I want to use IPython notebook and Pandas to consume a stream and dynamically update a plot every five seconds.

When I just use a print statement to print the data in text format, it works perfectly fine: the output cell just keeps printing data and adding new rows. But when I try to plot the data (and then update it in a loop), the plot never shows up in the output cell. But if I remove the loop, and just plot it once, it works fine.

Then I did some simple test:

```
i = pd.date_range('2013-1-1',periods=100,freq='s')
while True:
    plot(pd.Series(data=np.random.randn(100), index=i))
    #pd.Series(data=np.random.randn(100), index=i).plot() also tried this one
    time.sleep(5)
```

The output will not show anything until I manually interrupt the process (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>). And after I interrupt it, the plot shows correctly as multiple overlapped lines. But what I really want is a plot that shows up and gets updated every five seconds (or whenever the `plot()` function gets called, just like what print statement outputs I mentioned above, which works well). Only showing the final chart after the cell is completely done is *not* what I want.

I even tried to explicitly add the draw() function after each `plot()`, etc. None of them works. How can I dynamically update a plot by a *for*/*while* loop within one cell in IPython notebook?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Use the `IPython.display` module:

```
%matplotlib inline
import time
import pylab as pl
from IPython import display
for i in range(10):
    pl.plot(pl.randn(100))
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    display.display(pl.gcf())
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: this is not smooth option, the plot is recreated from scratch with cell going up and down in between

Comment: Adding `clear_output(wait=True)` solves this problem. See wabu's answer below.

Comment: You can do better these days with `%matplotlib nbagg` which gives you a live figure to play with.

Comment: @tcaswell I've added a new question asking how one uses `nbagg` to achieve this. (Pinging you in case you're interested in answering it.) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486642/what-is-the-currently-correct-way-to-dynamically-update-plots-in-jupyter-ipython

Comment: this works but also destroys anything else in the cell like the printed measures. Is there a way really just updating the plot and keeping everything else in place?

Comment: Rather than sleeping for 1 second between graph updates, is there a way to make the figure only update after a button press?

Comment: Why is this not working correctly if I use `subplots`?

Comment: This almost works perfectly, but starts to slow down appreciably about 20 images are displayed.

Answer (score 41):

A couple of improvement's on [HYRY's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21361994/revisions):

- call `display` before `clear_output` so that you end up with one plot, rather than two, when the cell is interrupted.
- catch the `KeyboardInterrupt`, so that the cell output isn't littered with the traceback.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from IPython import display
%matplotlib inline

i = pd.date_range('2013-1-1',periods=100,freq='s')

while True:
    try:
        plt.plot(pd.Series(data=np.random.randn(100), index=i))
        display.display(plt.gcf())
        display.clear_output(wait=True)
        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
```

Comment: Indeed, `display.display(gcf())` should go **BEFORE** `display.clear_output(wait=True)`

Comment: Thanks, @csta. Added it.

Comment: @herrlich10 Why should `display` be called before `clear_output`? Shouldn't you first clear the output and then display the new data, instead of doing it the other way around?

Comment: I am still getting a screen flicker with the graph updates, however it's not all the time. 
Is there a workaround to this?

Comment: If you are also trying to print text at the beginning of the loop, I find that this causes the graph to disappear, so that it is only visible for a split second. I do not have this problem when the `display()` call is placed after `clear_output()`.

Answer (score 36):

You can further improve this by adding `wait=True` to `clear_output`:

```
display.clear_output(wait=True)
display.display(pl.gcf())
```

Comment: +1. This is very important. I think HYRY's answer should be updated with this info.

Comment: This is good, but has the annoying side effect of clearing the print output as well.

Answer (score 7):

I tried many methods, but I found this as the simplest and the easiest way -> to add clear_output(wait=True), for example,

```
from IPython.display import clear_output

for i in range(n_iterations):
     clear_output(wait=True)
     x = some value
     y = some value
     plt.plot(x, y, '-r')
     plt.show()
```

This overwrites on the same plot, and gives an illusion of plot animation

Answer (score 4):

Adding a label to the other solutions posted here will keep adding new labels in every loop. To deal with that, clear the plot using `clf`.

For example:

```
for t in range(100):
   if t % refresh_rate == 0:

     plt.clf()
     plt.plot(history['val_loss'], 'r-', lw=2, label='val')
     plt.plot(history['training_loss'], 'b-', lw=1, label='training')
     plt.legend()
     display.clear_output(wait=True)
     display.display(plt.gcf())
```

Comment: Thanks `plt.clf()` works. However is there anyway to get rid of the flicker from the updates?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `show()` or `gcf().show()` after the `plot()` function. These will force the current figure to update (gcf() returns a reference for the current figure).

Comment: thanks. gcf().show() also works. Need to add the clear_output() suggested by HYRY to show stuff on the same fig

Comment: Is this in addition to "display.display(pl.gcf())"?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this. It accepts x,y as list and output a scatter plot plus a linear trend on the same plot.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
    
def live_plot(x, y, figsize=(7,5), title=''):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    plt.xlim(0, training_steps)
    plt.ylim(0, 100)
    x = [float(i) for i in x]
    y = [float(i) for i in y]
    
    if len(x) > 1:
        plt.scatter(x,y, label='axis y', color='k') 
        m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
        plt.plot(x, [x * m for x in x] + b)

    plt.title(title)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlabel('axis x')
    plt.ylabel('axis y')
    plt.show();
```

You just need to call `live_plot(x, y)` inside a loop. Here's how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A nice solution has been proposed by [@BlackHC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/854731/blackhc) in a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65400882/6361014).
It consists in using [`IPython.display.display`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display) with `display_id=True` to obtain a [handle](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display) and use the `update()` method on it.

For instance,

```
import time

from IPython.display import display
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import numpy as np


hdisplay_img = display(display_id=True)
hdisplay_txt = display(display_id=True)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
im = ax.imshow(np.random.random((10,10,3)))
plt.close()

def update(i):
    im.set_data(np.random.random((10,10,3)))
    ax.add_image(im)
    hdisplay_img.update(fig)
    hdisplay_txt.update(f"update {i}")

for f in range(10):
    update(f)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimal modern solution for notebooks in Jupyter Lab (version 3.6.1):

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.set(xlabel=f'Epochs', ylabel='Value',
       title='Dynamics')

for i in range(n_step):
   ...
   ax.plot(...)
   
   if i==0:
      ax.legend(labels, loc='upper right')
   else:
      display(fig, clear=True);
```

Notice! No need for neither `%matplotlib inline` nor `from IPython.display import clear_output, display` because
by default a new notebook already has a function with signature:

```
display(
    *objs,
    include=None,
    exclude=None,
    metadata=None,
    transient=None,
    display_id=None,
    raw=False,
    clear=False,
    **kwargs,
)
```

Note the keyword argument `clear`! Setting it to `True` makes a deal.