# Dynamically update plot in iPython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

As referred in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360361/how-to-dynamically-update-a-plot-in-a-loop-in-ipython-notebook-within-one-cell), I am trying to update a plot dynamically in an iPython notebook (in one cell).
The difference is that I don't want to plot new lines, but that my x_data and y_data are growing at each iteration of some loop.

What I'd like to do is:

```
import numpy as np
import time
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 100]) # supoose I know what the limits are going to be
plt.ion()
plt.show()
x = []
y = []
for i in range(10):
     x = np.append(x, i)
     y = np.append(y, i**2)
     # update the plot so that it shows y as a function of x
     time.sleep(0.5)
```

but I want the plot to have a legend, and if I do

```
from IPython import display
import time
import numpy as np
plt.axis([0, 10, 0, 100]) # supoose I know what the limits are going to be
plt.ion()
plt.show()
x = []
y = []
for i in range(10):
    x = np.append(x, i)
    y = np.append(y, i**2)
    plt.plot(x, y, label="test")
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    time.sleep(0.3)
plt.legend()
```

I end up with a legend which contains 10 items. If I put the `plt.legend()` inside the loop, the legend grows at each iteration... Any solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, you are creating a new Axes object for every time you `plt.plot` in the loop.

So, if you clear the current axis (`plt.gca().cla()`) before you use `plt.plot`, and put the legend inside the loop, it works without the legend growing each time:

```
import numpy as np
import time
from IPython import display

x = []
y = []
for i in range(10):
    x = np.append(x, i)
    y = np.append(y, i**2)
    plt.gca().cla() 
    plt.plot(x,y,label='test')
    plt.legend()
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    display.display(plt.gcf()) 
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

**EDIT:**
As @tcaswell pointed out in comments, using the `%matplotlib notebook` magic command gives you a live figure which can update and redraw.

Comment: Better, but if I do that, the legend is not visible until the loop has ended

Comment: really? that works for me. Where did you put the legend? It needs to be before the two `display` lines

Comment: I had put the legend() inside the loop, but at the last line of the loop. Now I've put it after plot() and it works fine

Comment: great, glad that helped.

Comment: One more thing: when I run my snippet (adding your line and changing legend() location), I end up with two images. Any idea why?

Comment: try switching the order of the `display.clear_output` and `display.display` lines. That is discussed in more detail in the answers to the question you linked to in the Q

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87172/discussion-between-m-massias-and-tom).

Comment: You can do better if you use `%matplotlib notebook` which gives you a live figure that you can update and re-draw (as well as pan/zoom and have mouse+keyboard events)

Comment: @tcaswell: very nice, I didn't know about `%matplotlib notebook`. Updating the answer...

Comment: Re: @P. Camilleri's comment:  I added `%matplotlib inline` at the end of my loop (or at the end of the cell, either way worked.) as a hack to remove that second plot from appearing (when the cell ends). Switching the order of `display.clear_output` and `display.display` did not work for me.  I have not yet found the correct way to use `%matplotlib notebook` for my dynamic plot, so this works as a temp solution in the meantime.  I use `%matplotlib inline` everywhere else in my notebook, so resetting it probably makes sense for me anyway :-)