# Ipython notebook: show for-loop images "realtime", before next step

Tags: for-loop, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Running following code in an ipython/jupyter notebook:

```
for i in range(4):

    # any figure
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(range(i), range(i))
    fig.show()

    # do something that takes a long time:
    a = fib(500000)
```

results in all the figures being visible at the same time (after the 4th loop).

How can I change my setup so that the figures become visible as soon as they have been calculated (before the next step in the for loop)?

N.B. I'm using %matplotlib inline

Comment: Duplicated several times: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360361/how-to-dynamically-update-a-plot-in-a-loop-in-ipython-notebook-within-one-cell), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051408/dynamically-update-plot-in-ipython-notebook)...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, import display:

`from IPython import display`

and replace `fig.show()` by `display.display(fig)`