# How to update interactive figure in loop with JupyterLab

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to update an interactive matplotlib figure while in a loop using JupyterLab. I am able to do this if I create the figure in a different cell from the loop, but I would prefer to create the figure and run the loop in the same cell.

Simple Code Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

%matplotlib widget

fig = plt.figure()

for i in range(5):
    x = list(range(i+2))
    xx = [x**2 for x in x]
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(x, xx)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    
    time.sleep(1)
```

If `fig = plt.figure()` is in the same cell as the loop the figure is not updated until the loop finishes:

[image: Not Dynamically Updating]

If I create the figure in a different cell I get the dynamic update, but I would like to be able to create the figure in the same cell if possible so the output is below the loop:

[image: Requires extra cell]

I have tried several answers in other questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360361/how-to-dynamically-update-a-plot-in-a-loop-in-ipython-notebook-within-one-cell), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051408/dynamically-update-plot-in-ipython-notebook), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486642/what-is-the-currently-correct-way-to-dynamically-update-plots-in-jupyter-ipython)) however, they do not seem to work with interactive figures in JupyterLab. I am using the [jupyter/scipy-notebook](https://jupyter-docker-stacks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/selecting.html#jupyter-scipy-notebook) docker image as my environment, so I believe everything is set up correctly.

Is there any way to get the dynamic update in the same cell as the figure is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use asyncio, taking advantage of the IPython event loop:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import asyncio
%matplotlib widget
fig = plt.figure()


async def update():
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        x = list(range(i + 2))
        xx = [x**2 for x in x]
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(x, xx)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(update());
```

[image: gif with a notebook with single cell being run and the animation progressing as expected]

Comment: Using this approach, it is no longer possible to stop the computation with the `interrupt the kernel` (stop-)button. Is there a simple way around that issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66658900/15515166 the second half of this

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use `asyncio`, you can use `display(..., display_id=True)` to obtain a handle and use `.update()` on it:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
%matplotlib widget
fig = plt.figure()

hfig = display(fig, display_id=True)


def update():
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        x = list(range(i + 2))
        xx = [x**2 for x in x]
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(x, xx)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        hfig.update(fig)
        time.sleep(1)

update()

plt.close(fig)
```

PS: Make sure to close your figure!

Comment: I like the look of this solution, but for me it draws two figures, one in the widget and one as an image. Do you know if there is a way to remove the second plot?

Comment: What notebook/jupyter-lab version are you using? I'm using notebook 6.1.4 and it works. (Also works in jupyter-lab.)

I've only seen a second plot appear without `plt.close(fig)`

Comment: @BlackHC I think you should mention the importance of closing the figure in the text of your answer.