# Running a small python program in background inside Jupyter notebook without blocking the main process

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

Let suppose I have this simple function:

```
def fun():
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        sleep(2)
```

and I want to run it in background without interrupting the main code flow, is this achievable?

I tried saving the code in `test.py` and did:

```
from IPython.lib.backgroundjobs import BackgroundJobFunc

with open('test.py') as code:
    job = BackgroundJobFunc(exec, code.read())


result = job.run()
```

It printed 0 and exited.
I also tried:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

process = Popen(['python', 'test.py.py'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)

stdout, stderr = process.communicate()

print(stdout)
```

and

```
from threading import Thread

thread = Thread(target = fun)
thread.start()
thread.join()
print("thread finished...exiting")
```

Both blocked the main process. Could not do anything before it finished it's execution.
Is there a different way?

Comment: To a degree you can use asyncio like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63384326/how-to-update-interactive-figure-in-loop-with-jupyterlab/63517891#63517891). You may also be interested in [akernel](https://github.com/davidbrochart/akernel) (asynchronous Python kernel for Jupyter).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a daemon thread solved the problem ( **with one problem that it prints the value in `cell` you're currently printing / working**)

```
 t1 = threading.Thread(target=fun)
 t1.setDaemon(True)
 t1.start()
```

Any corrections / suggestions to this?