# What is the currently correct way to dynamically update plots in Jupyter/iPython?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

In the answers to [how to dynamically update a plot in a loop in ipython notebook (within one cell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360361/how-to-dynamically-update-a-plot-in-a-loop-in-ipython-notebook-within-one-cell), an example is given of how to dynamically update a plot inside a Jupyter notebook within a Python loop. However, this works by destroying and re-creating the plot on every iteration, and a comment in one of the threads notes that this situation can be improved by using the new-ish `%matplotlib nbagg` magic, which provides an interactive figure embedded in the notebook, rather than a static image.

However, this wonderful new `nbagg` feature seems to be completely undocumented as far as I can tell, and I'm unable to find an example of how to use it to dynamically update a plot. Thus my question is, **how does one efficiently update an existing plot in a Jupyter/Python notebook, using the nbagg backend?** Since dynamically updating plots in matplotlib is a tricky issue in general, a simple working example would be an enormous help. A pointer to any documentation on the topic would also be extremely helpful.

To be clear what I'm asking for: what I want to do is to run some simulation code for a few iterations, then draw a plot of its current state, then run it for a few more iterations, then update the plot to reflect the current state, and so on. So the idea is to draw a plot and then, without any interaction from the user, update the data in the plot without destroying and re-creating the whole thing.

Here is some slightly modified code from the answer to the linked question above, which achieves this by re-drawing the whole figure every time. I want to achieve the same result, but more efficiently using `nbagg`.

```
%matplotlib inline
import time
import pylab as pl
from IPython import display
for i in range(10):
    pl.clf()
    pl.plot(pl.randn(100))
    display.display(pl.gcf())
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Here is an example that updates a plot in a loop. It updates the data in the figure and does not redraw the whole figure every time. It does block execution, though if you're interested in running a finite set of simulations and saving the results somewhere, it may not be a problem for you.

The `%matplotlib widget` magic requires the `ipympl` Matplotlib Jupyter Extension  package. You can install a working environment with `pip install jupyter ipympl`

```
%matplotlib widget
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def pltsin(ax, colors=['b']):
    x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
    if ax.lines:
        for line in ax.lines:
            line.set_xdata(x)
            y = np.random.random(size=(100,1))
            line.set_ydata(y)
    else:
        for color in colors:
            y = np.random.random(size=(100,1))
            ax.plot(x, y, color)
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
plt.show()

# run this cell to dynamically update plot
for f in range(5):
    pltsin(ax, ['b', 'r'])
    time.sleep(1)
```

I put this [up on nbviewer here](http://nbviewer.org/gist/branning/c8e63ce81be0391260b1), and here's [a direct link to the gist](https://gist.github.com/branning/c8e63ce81be0391260b1)

Comment: Great, that seems to work nicely. The lack of interactivity while it's running is not a big problem for me. One slightly odd thing: if I change the `while True:` to a for loop, when the loop ends I get two static images of the last plot, rather than an interactive nbagg one. Any idea why that is?

Comment: I changed the while to a for loop and tried it on tmpnb.org, and but I'm not seeing a second image or a loss of interactivity. Shot in the dark, but you could try moving the loop around the call to the function, rather than having the loop in the function.

    for f in range(10):
        pltsin(ax)
        time.sleep(1)

Comment: How does one plot two lines overlaid together on this plot?

Comment: @jfhc you'd need to add as many `ax.lines` as you want plots, then use `line.set_data`, and call `fig.canvas.draw` afterwards to update the figure. I modified the example to show how to do that.

Comment: @pneumatics Unfortunately it has some problems with Matplotlib 2.0 on Retina display: in the loop plots are twice smaller that usually.

Comment: this doesn't do anything on Windows 7. no plots shown at all

Comment: @Aksakal can you plot other things? If I paste the code above at http://try.jupyter.org, it works okay

Comment: It seems the figure is not given the time to resize itself correctly. So I had a much better experience when putting a `plt.show()` and moving the for-loop to the next cell.

Comment: The `%matplotlib notebook` backend is not supported in jupyter lab because they disabled appending raw javascript to the cells. It works fine in regular jupyter notebook, still.

Comment: Anyone know what `lines` is?

Comment: @MasayoMusic it's the list of lines contained by the Axes. `lines` is a private API, probably should call `get_lines` instead.

Comment: Be sure that you have the %matplotlib notebook in the same jupyter notebook cell as your plot - I spent over 2 hours today troubleshooting this because I had %matplotlib notebook in the first cell with the import statments

Comment: Can someone confirm this does *no* work on Google Colab?

Comment: @aguazul, I tried to put %matplotlib notebook in the first cell, and it still works on my jupyter notebook. My colleague also tried on Binder with %matplotlib notebook in the first cell, it still works on Binder. May I ask what is the version of your jupyter notebook? Mine is 5.2.2

Comment: In jupyter lab I had to use `%matplotlib widget` instead of `%matplotlib notebook`. Also the plot changes dynamically only if I add `plt.show()` and move the for-loop to the next cell (under the plot) as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest suggested.

Comment: @JulienM on Google Colab, %matplotlib notebook and %matplotlib widget show no output, even when you !pip install ipympl when using widget. I get output with %matplotlib inline, but that backend cannot dynamically update plots

Answer (score 32):

I'm using jupyter-lab and this works for me (adapt it to your case):

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import collections
%matplotlib inline

def live_plot(data_dict, figsize=(7,5), title=''):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    for label,data in data_dict.items():
        plt.plot(data, label=label)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlabel('epoch')
    plt.legend(loc='center left') # the plot evolves to the right
    plt.show();
```

Then in a loop you populate a dictionary and you pass it to `live_plot()`:

```
data = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in range(100):
    data['foo'].append(np.random.random())
    data['bar'].append(np.random.random())
    data['baz'].append(np.random.random())
    live_plot(data)
```

make sure you have a few cells below the plot, otherwise the view snaps in place each time the plot is redrawn.

Comment: this creates a new plot each time rather than updating the existing plot

Comment: Correct. I haven't found a better way of having a dynamical plot in jupyter-lab.

Comment: Is there a way to set how long it waits between iterations? rather than just having a 'wait = True'

Comment: Every time the plot is redrawn, the graph flickers. Is there a way to fix this problem? 
I have a few empty cells under the plot, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: @MasayoMusic see "Flickering and jumping output" in https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/ipywidgets/latest/ipywidgets.pdf

Comment: from IPython.display import clear_output is the secret that works well for me, thanks!

Comment: This takes 0.087s per frame for me (11hz) fwiw

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want to clear all outputs, you can use `display_id=True` to obtain a handle and use `.update()` on it:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

from IPython import display

def pltsin(ax, *,hdisplay, colors=['b']):
    x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
    if ax.lines:
        for line in ax.lines:
            line.set_xdata(x)
            y = np.random.random(size=(100,1))
            line.set_ydata(y)
    else:
        for color in colors:
            y = np.random.random(size=(100,1))
            ax.plot(x, y, color)
    hdisplay.update(fig)


fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
hdisplay = display.display("", display_id=True)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
for f in range(5):
    pltsin(ax, colors=['b', 'r'], hdisplay=hdisplay)
    time.sleep(1)
    
plt.close(fig)
```

(adapted from @pneumatics)

Comment: This one works for Jupyter notebook, nice and smooth. 

Answer (score 1):

I've adapted @Ziofil answer and modified it to accept x,y as list and output a scatter plot plus a linear trend on the same plot.

```
from IPython.display import clear_output
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
    
def live_plot(x, y, figsize=(7,5), title=''):
    clear_output(wait=True)
    plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
    plt.xlim(0, training_steps)
    plt.ylim(0, 100)
    x= [float(i) for i in x]
    y= [float(i) for i in y]
    
    if len(x) > 1:
        plt.scatter(x,y, label='axis y', color='k') 
        m, b = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
        plt.plot(x, [x * m for x in x] + b)

    plt.title(title)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlabel('axis x')
    plt.ylabel('axis y')
    plt.show();
```

you just need to call `live_plot(x, y)` inside a loop.
here's how it looks:
[image]

Comment: This code runs very slowly for me :/ For plotting x=np.linspace(0, 2*3.141592, 100), y=sin(x + phase) for 100 loops without sleeping, it took 8 seconds. Note that this is with the ployfit removed

Comment: (0.087s per frame or 11hz)

Answer (score 0):

The `canvas.draw` method of the figure dynamically updates its graphs, for the current figure:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

plt.gcf().canvas.draw()
```