# Why is Jupyter Notebook creating duplicate plots when making updating plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to make plots in a Jupyter Notebook that update every second or so. Right now, I just have a simple code which is working:

```
%matplotlib inline
import time
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython import display

for i in range(10):
    plt.close()
    a = np.random.randint(100,size=100)
    b = np.random.randint(100,size=100)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1)
    ax[0].plot(a)
    ax[0].set_title('A')
    ax[1].plot(b)
    ax[1].set_title('B')

    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Which updated the plots I have created every second. However, at the end, there is an extra copy of the plots:

[image]

Why is it doing this? And how can I make this not happen? Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a hint of this on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486642/what-is-the-currently-correct-way-to-dynamically-update-plots-in-jupyter-ipython?rq=1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `inline` backend is set-up so that when each cell is finished executing, any matplotlib plot created in the cell will be displayed.

You are displaying your figure once using the `display` function, and then the figure is being displayed again automatically by the inline backend.

The easiest way to prevent this is to add `plt.close()` at the end of the code in your cell.

Answer (score 7):

Another alternative would be to add `;` at the end of the line! I am experiencing the same issue with `statsmodels` methods to plot the autocorrelation of a time series (`statsmodels.graphics.tsaplot.plot_acf()`):

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf

plot_acf(daily_outflow["count"]);
```

[image: cell_ends_with_semicolon]

Comment: This solution work for Jupyter Notebook with Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

Despite using `%matplotlib inline`, it's not working for some libraries, such as `statsmodels`. I recommend always use `plt.show()` at the end of your code.