# Dynamic plot in python jupyter notebook using drawnow

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to plot some data from a camera dynamically using drawnow. However, the dynamic plotting (using matplotlib and drawnow) doesn't seem to be working on jupyter notebook.

It's currently working in Pycharm.

My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from drawnow import *


x = np.random.randn(10, 2)


def function_to_draw_figure():
    plt.plot(i, j, 'r.')


plt.ion()
figure()
for i, j in x:
    drawnow(function_to_draw_figure)
    plt.xlim(-1, 1)
    plt.ylim(-1, 1)
    plt.pause(0.5)
```

I would expect this example to plot 10 points dynamically on the same figure (as in pycharm). What actually happens is that multiple figures appear rather than one.

Any thoughts why I am not able to do it using jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never quite understood the purpose of `drawnow`. You should get the exact same result just calling your function.

Neither drawnow nor its equivalent simply using `plt.ion()` and `plt.draw()` or `plt.pause()` will work in jupyter notebooks. For sure not using the `%matplotlib inline` backend (because you cannot animate pngs); but also not with the `%matplotlib notebook` backend due to the event loop which has not been started until the final figure is shown.

Options to show an animation in jupyter notebooks are listed in 
[Animation in iPython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532498/animation-in-ipython-notebook).

The recommended way would be to create a `FuncAnimation`.

The animation from above would then look like

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(10, 2)


def function_to_draw_figure(i):
    line.set_data(*x[i,:])

plt.figure()
line, = plt.plot([], marker="o")
plt.xlim(0, 1)
plt.ylim(0, 1)

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), function_to_draw_figure, frames=len(x), 
                    interval=500, repeat=False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code is stacking the figures not updating them.

Comment: At the final iteration (final figure), you should see only one point (x[9,:]).

Comment: Really? So `drawnow` clears the figure for each call?

Comment: Yes, If you run my code in pycharm or any other IDE, it will plot each point dynamically . At each iteration, you plot the current point on the same figure. The point will jump from a position to next position.

Comment: I see. It will even clear the complete figure. Pretty unefficient if you ask me. Btw, the [drawnow page](https://github.com/stsievert/python-drawnow) clearly states that it's not working in IPython (hence also not in Juypter). I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I would like to know why using * in *x[i,:]. The code seems work in both cases without pointing to the variable.

Comment: For `plot` the unpacking was necessary. However, `set_data` accepts a 2D array, or 2 1D arrays. So it doesn't matter. This is just a leftover from previous code. Remove it or leave it, just as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using matplotlib with the `notebook` backend in your Jupyter notebook?

You can do this by adding `%matplotlib notebook` magic command in a cell at the beginning of your notebook (e.g. right after importing `matplotlib`)

More info here: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/plotting.html

Comment: I am not familiar with drawnow, maybe this example showing how to update the data in the figure without redrawing the whole figure every time can help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34486703/2699660