# how to print jupyter background job output in cell it was launched from?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, output, cell, background-process

When launching a background job from an IPython Jupyter Notebook, how can I make the printed output appear in the cell it was launched from, rather than in the cell I am currently working in?

The `print()` command seems to print into the current working cell, not into the cell that the background job was launched from. Is there a way to make it print nicely in the cell it was launched from? This is particularly relevant when running multiple background job sets, as to determine which jobset was responsible for that line of output.

Edit: it occurs with any code but here is a small snippet to reproduce it:

```
from IPython.lib import backgroundjobs as bg
import time
def launchJob():
    for i in range(100):
       print('x')
       time.sleep(1)
jobs = bg.BackgroundJobManager()
for r in range(3):
    jobs.new("launchJob()")
```

that does exactly what you'd expect it to do, print 3 x's every second in the output under the cell. Now go to the next cell and type `1+1` and execute it. The output 2 appears, but also any remaining x's get printed in this new cell rather in the original cell.

I am looking for a way to specifically tell my job to always print to the original cell it was executed from, as to obtain sort of a log in the background, or to generate a bunch of plots in the background, or any kind of data that I want in one place rather than appearing all over my notebook.

Comment: Can you provide the code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Added some code that reproduces the problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`IPython.lib.backgoundjobs.BackgroundJobManager.new` documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/7.9.0/api/generated/IPython.lib.backgroundjobs.html#IPython.lib.backgroundjobs.BackgroundJobManager.new) states:

> All threads running share the same standard output. Thus, if your background jobs generate output, it will come out on top of whatever you are currently writing. For this reason, background jobs are best used with silent functions which simply return their output.

In GitHub pull request [#856](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/856) of IPython (October 2011), the developers discussed this issue and concluded that [keeping the output in the original cell would be difficult to implement](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/856#issuecomment-2422095). Hence, they decided to [table the idea](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/856#issuecomment-2422431) and in the latest version (7.9.0 at the time of writing) it still has not been solved.

In the mean time, a workaround could be to store the output in a variable, or to write/[pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) the output to a file and print/[display](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.display.html) it once the background jobs are finished.

Comment: Thanks for looking that up, that's unfortunate. Regarding workarounds: can I store the output in a variable/file if the background process (not written or controlled by me) is a python script that uses print(...) for everything?

Comment: If you have no control over the background processes themselves, it becomes more complicated. If it were regular processes, you would be able to capture the `stdout` using [`IPython.utils.capture.capture_output`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.utils.capture.html#IPython.utils.capture.capture_output). Unfortunately this does not seem to work with background processes and I do not know of any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

While it is not a direct answer to my question as it does not work with the print command, I did manage to solve my problem partially in the sense that I can have graphs updating in the back (and can hence log any kind of data on them as-we-go without any need to re-run).

Some proof of concept code below, based on [What is the currently correct way to dynamically update plots in Jupyter/iPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486642/what-is-the-currently-correct-way-to-dynamically-update-plots-in-jupyter-ipython)

```
%matplotlib notebook

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from IPython.lib import backgroundjobs as bg

def pltsin(ax, colors=['b']):
    x = np.linspace(0,1,100)
    if ax.lines:
        for line in ax.lines:
            line.set_xdata(x)
            y = np.random.random(size=(100,1))
            line.set_ydata(y)
    else:
        for color in colors:
            y = np.random.random(size=(100,1))
            ax.plot(x, y, color)
    fig.canvas.draw()

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)

def launchJob():
    for i in range(100):
        pltsin(ax, ['b', 'r'])
        time.sleep(1)
jobs = bg.BackgroundJobManager()
jobs.new("launchJob()")
```

While this is running, typing 1+1 in another cell does not disrupt the updating of the figure. For me this was a game changer, so I'll post this in case anyone is helped by it.

Comment: That actually helped me create a solution for my problem, thanks! I've awarded you the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

@Peter As other answers address the method of doing this using pickle or Output file, I would like to suggest alternate method. 
I will advise that you should initiate print operation in parent window. When the certain criteria for execution is reached in child process window then return those values to print function in parent.

Use `%matplotlib inline` to print the values in cell of parent. This prints the outputs and visuals in the same cell.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Would you mind adding example code, or point to a relevant read?