# Dynamic update and show gym env in Notebook, done but the next cell goes up and down. How to deal with it?

Tags: python, matplotlib, openai-api

I have created an openai gym env and would like to render it in vscode notebook.
Following previous answers, [How to dynamically update a plot in a loop in IPython notebook (within one cell)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360361/how-to-dynamically-update-a-plot-in-a-loop-in-ipython-notebook-within-one-cell?newreg=2782d9ba65c240c5a135c5d56e4c7ce7), my code is as follows:

```
import gym
from IPython import display
from IPython.display import Image
%matplotlib inline

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
# plt.ion()

env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env.reset()

img = plt.imshow(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))

done = False
while not done:
    action = env.action_space.sample()
    observation, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)

    img.set_data(env.render(mode='rgb_array'))
    display.display(plt.gcf())
    display.clear_output(wait=True)

env.close()
```

This solution did make it but the next cell keep going up and down while clearing output and re-creating images.
**Does anyone could help me to solve it?** Thank you in advance.